# IOException - Unexpected end of stream while reading html file

Tags: java, android, download, ioexception

I am trying to download the content of a php page (it is just 3 words), but I am getting `java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream`. This is the code for downloading:

```
// Download file list
        String zipListUrl = baseUrl + ziplist;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(zipListUrl);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            // txtResult.setText(HttpHelper.request(response));
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));


            String line = null;
            String result = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // fileNames.add(line);
                result += line;
            }
            in.close();
            // Turn arraylist into simple array
            // finalFileNames = (String[]) fileNames.toArray();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, /* Arrays.toString(finalFileNames) */result);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception ex1  = " + ex.toString());
        }
```

And here is the exception:

```
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101): unexpected end of stream
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101): java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.close(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:58)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:83)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at net.zedge.android.api.request.BaseApiRequest.run(BaseApiRequest.java:50)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at net.zedge.android.api.request.BaseApiRequest$1.run(BaseApiRequest.java:84)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-18 11:11:04.312: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101): unexpected end of stream
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101): java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.close(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:58)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:83)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at net.zedge.android.api.request.BaseApiRequest.run(BaseApiRequest.java:50)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at net.zedge.android.api.request.BaseApiRequest$1.run(BaseApiRequest.java:84)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-18 11:11:04.342: W/HttpTransport(3101):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I tried debugging, and the last value of `result` is this: 
`null<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /ziplist.php was not found on this server.</p><p>Additionally, a 404 Not Founderror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p></body></html>`

Any ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Is your PHP page possibly setting Content-Lenght (incorrectly)?

Comment: After your edit; seems /ziplist.php just plain does not exist on your server. Check your URL.

Comment: You were right about both things :) - i missed a folder name from the url, and also didn't have Content-Lenght header. Write your answer and I will accept it. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that Content-Length is set incorrectly ([the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/2503556d17b28c7b4e6e514540a77df1627857d0%5E/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/http/FixedLengthOutputStream.java) shows that FixedLengthOutputStream.close throws IOException on a size mismatch)

Also, in your edit you're showing that your page is returning a '404, which indicates that you're not using the correct URL for `ziplist.php`. Double check the URL you're using :)