# IOException: unexpected end of stream thrown HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, inputstream, ioexception

I am getting an `IOException: unexpected end of stream` when trying to read the `inputStream` of an `HttpUrlConnection`. I have tested with other URL's like `http://google.com` and added `urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");` testing for an error on another helpful persons advice but no error occurred. My target SDK and buildSDK match. I am fetching results using the same class for other fragments with different URL's without problems. Since trying to change to another API I've come across this problem.

The URL I'm trying to fetch JSON results from - `http://eventregistry.org/json/article?query=%7B%22%24query%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourceUri%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%22bbc.co.uk%22%5D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22lang%22%3A%22eng%22%7D%5D%7D%7D&action=getArticles&apikey=342f5f25-75ac-44b5-8da0441508e871e8&resultType=articles&articlesSortBy=date&articlesCount=10&articlesIncludeArticleImage=true`

My code to fetch the JSON -

```
package com.example.android.greennewswire;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class QueryUtils {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private QueryUtils(){
    }

    public static ArrayList<News> fetchNewsData(String requestUrl) {
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {String testString = readUrl(requestUrl); Log.i(LOG_TAG, "testString: " + testString);
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error making HTTP request", e);
        }
        if (jsonResponse == null) {
            return new ArrayList<News>();
        }
        ArrayList<News> news = extractBooks(jsonResponse);

        return news;
    }

    public static URL createUrl(String stringUrl){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Malformed URL", e);
        } return url;
    }

    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = null;

        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStream errorStream = null;

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            urlConnection.connect();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());


            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromInputStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String string = e.getCause().toString();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem reading from input stream, " + string, e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }


    private static String readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

Stack trace

```
Problem reading from input stream, java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=14639 content=7b2261727469636c6573223a7b22726573756c7473223a5b7b226964223a2231...
                                                                           java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{eventregistry.org:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=185.49.3.27 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:905)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:789)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298450/1967021 - looks like there;s an issue in site setting Content-length

Comment: Can I resolve this at my client side?